# How to write parameter infinity under MS windows xp command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

There is a binary exe that executes under windows xp command prompt. One parameter required
is infinity (∞）. My system is win xp 5.1.26 (in command prompt window). How to write that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to copy the infinity symbol to your clipboard, right-click into the command prompt window and select "Paste". If that doesn't work, check the settings.

Alternatively, [alt codes](http://usefulshortcuts.com/alt-codes/maths-alt-codes.php)!

Comment: it requires infinity integer, not that symbol. Is that like MAX_INT or something else.

Comment: Well, infinity isn't an actual number and can't be expressed as integer. What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: The prompt says I need integer parameter.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. But why are you trying to pass it infinity? Integers have an upper bound (i. e. you can't store arbitrarily high values).

Comment: how to check the maximum integer that can be used in ms xp command window?

Comment: Thanks, the command is CC[][], manual says [] can be set infinity.

Comment: @Warren What program is it? Please revise your question so this information will be more useful to others.